# Jasmine test case failing due to ''TypeError: _co.arr.slice is not a function"

Tags: angular, jasmine

In my .ts file, I have 'arr' being assigned an array fetched from an api call.
The respective .html file uses

*ngFor="let item of arr.slice(0, historyLimit)"

When I write a test case,
I get following error:

TypeError: _co.arr.slice is not a function

Comment: it is not recommended to use functions in *ngFor loops.  try to perform the processing in typescript and use the result in angular

Comment: Be sure you are doing the api call in an beforeEach where you are calling done() when it finishes, and be sure you aren't trying to call `arr.slice()` before it is assigned to the response data.